# RuntimeException in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm getting a crash when my user tries to load a page. The error comes from a query in my database. This table is new to the database but when I load the app myself I get no problems no matter what I try and everything works fine. He is using a Kindle Fire fyi. Here is the stack trace. I have no idea why this is happening except that I cant recreate the error no matter what I do.

Here is the query

```
public HashMap<String, String> getimagelocation() {
            HashMap<String, String> wordList = new HashMap<String, String>();
            SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM LOGO";
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                        //HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    wordList.put("imagetext", cursor.getString(1));

                       //wordList.add(map);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                database.close();
            }return wordList;
        }
```

And the Stack Trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2030)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2055)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1176)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4532)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1566)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1540)
at com.superstore.st.Database.getimagelocation(Database.java:126)
at com.superstore.st.SuperStoreMenu.onCreateSuperStoreMenu(SuperStoreMenu.java:2955)
at com.superstore.st.SuperStoreMenu.onCreate(SuperStoreMenu.java)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4635)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1994)
... 11 more
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the problem, but can you close your cursor after iterating and later close the database?